# How do I fix /dev/stderr pointing to /dev/null instead of current terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, stderr

How do fix when /dev/stderr is pointing to /dev/null, because of which, all err messages are redirected to /dev/null without using the `>` operation.

```
~  tty
/dev/pts/0
 ~  l /dev/stdout
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jun  1 18:06 /dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
 ~  l /dev/stdin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jun  1 18:06 /dev/stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
 ~  l /proc/self/fd/0
lrwx------ 1 avirukbasak avirukbasak 64 Jun  1 18:20 /proc/self/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/0
 ~  l /proc/self/fd/2
l-wx------ 1 avirukbasak avirukbasak 64 Jun  1 18:20 /proc/self/fd/2 -> /dev/null
 ~  l /proc/self/fd/1
lrwx------ 1 avirukbasak avirukbasak 64 Jun  1 18:20 /proc/self/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/0
```

An image of the terminal is also attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfkqU.jpg)

Comment: How did you end up in this state in the first place?

Comment: What's your above environment? Is this in Docker or PHP?

Comment: Idk how i ended up with this, must've done something that should not be done.

Comment: I believe it's docker, this is a Google cloud shell VM. Signing into the VM after 1 hr didn't fix the issue tho. After 1 hr the VM is supposed to shut down.

Comment: I've found the cause of trouble, since the VM doesn't support system wide changes, I've used a startup script to install zsh. Then in bashrc, I've done `zsh 2> /dev/null` to run zsh, so that incase zsh isn't installed, no errors are reported and installation is re-tried. But this is does what `exec 2> /dev/null` would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `exec` to change the current shell's file descriptors:

```
exec 2>/dev/tty
```

Use `command -v` to check whether a program is installed:

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then
    if command -v zsh >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        zsh
    fi
fi
```